# Is it possible to use several disks in the pool and some disks as local disks?

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, storage-spaces-direct

I have 4-node S2D cluster with 12 disks each on Windows Server 2016 Insider Preview 16257. I applied this settings by Cosmos Darwin to prevent adding new disks to the pool automatically

[Is there any way to prevent Storage Spaces Direct from automatically adding disks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/850478/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-storage-spaces-direct-from-automatically-adding-disk)

but when I connect new disk, with this cmdlet I can see (after few minutes), that the new disks are in the pool

```
(Get-PhysicalDisk | ? mediatype -eq hdd).cannotpoolreason
```

Is there another settings to modify? Is it possible to use local disk in every node within Storage Spaces Direct? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Nope. As a workaround you may want to patch the registry and ask your disks to report S2D-incompatible drive type, they will be ignored by S2D by default in such a case.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/resolving-enable-clusters2d-bus-type-support-issue-on-some-storage-controllers

Answer (score 1):

I second the [BaronSamedi1958's answer](https://serverfault.com/users/201494/baronsamedi1958). There is nothing else could be done. And yet Storage Spaces Direct is too buggy to run production. I believe you use Preview version for nothing but evaluation.

A similar thread on TechNet https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c743e652-012b-4145-893e-105474a9189e/s2d-auto-pooling?forum=winserverfiles